# PDO request returns only one result where there should be more

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have created this function:

```
<?php

$pdo_db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=' . $db_host . ';dbname=' . $db_name, $db_user_name, $db_password );

function qlist_pdo( $fields, $tables, $where_fields='', $where_values='', $order='', $limit='' ) {

GLOBAL $pdo_db; // ignore this, it will be in class later. This is just for test purposes

if ( $order ) $order = ' ORDER BY ' . $order;
if ( $limit ) $limit = ' LIMIT ' . $limit; 

if ( is_array( $where_fields ) && is_array( $where_values ) && isset( $where_fields ) && isset( $where_values ) ) {

    if ( sizeof( $where_fields ) != sizeof( $where_values ) ) {
        die( "Query error: where <strong>field</strong> count doesn't match <strong>value</strong> count!" );
    } else {

        $where = ' WHERE ';
        foreach( $where_fields as $key => $value ) {
            $where .= $key . ' ' . $value . '=? ';
        }
        $where = substr( $where, 0, -1 );

        echo $query = "SELECT " . $fields . " FROM " . $tables . $where . $order . $limit;
        $qp = $pdo_db -> prepare( $query );

        foreach ( $where_values as $key => $val ) {
            $qp -> bindParam( $key+1, $val );
        }           

    }

} else {
    echo $query = "SELECT " . $fields . " FROM " . $tables . $order . $limit;
    $qp = $pdo_db -> prepare( $query );
}

$qp -> execute();
$result = $qp -> fetchAll();

return $result;

}

?>
```

And I call it like this:

```
$result = qlist_pdo( "*", "list", array( '' => 'id', 'OR' => 'id' ), array( '2', '8' ), 'id DESC' );
```

It works fine, but gives me only 1 row as result ( where it should be 2 ), when I set the where parameters. If I call it without the were parameters like this:

```
$result = qlist_pdo( "*", "list", '', '', 'id DESC' );
```

It returns all rows. Why is that and what am I doing wrong?

Query generated:

```
SELECT * FROM list WHERE id=? OR id=? ORDER BY id DESC
```

Parameters generated:

```
1, 2
2, 8
```

*[EDIT]* It looks like it only adds the 2nd parameter. If I change `OR` to `AND` it still gives one result, even though it should give no rows at all ( since there can't be ID = 2 AND ID = 8 option ).

*[EDIT2]* I set up query log and got what I was thinking of. The actual query is `SELECT * FROM list WHERE  id='8' OR id='8' ORDER BY id DESC`

Comment: it would help to see the 2 generated queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, this was strange, but it seems that I needed a ref when binding the parameters.

Instead of:

```
foreach ( $where_values as $key => $val ) {
```

I needed:

```
foreach ( $where_values as $key => &$val ) {
```

Dunno why, but the **&** was the only thing I needed to add to my code.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the parameters as strings, but they are integers.

I would suggest passing the array in a different way:

```
$result = 
   qlist_pdo( "*", "list", 
   array( '' => 'id', 'OR' => 'id' ), array( 2, 8 ), 'id DESC' );
```

Your function should look like this:

```
function qlist_pdo( $fields, $tables, $where_fields = '', $where_values = '', $order = '', $limit = '' )
{
  if ( $order )
    $order = ' ORDER BY ' . $order;
  if ( $limit )
    $limit = ' LIMIT ' . $limit;

  if ( is_array( $where_fields ) && is_array( $where_values ) && isset( $where_fields ) && isset( $where_values ) ) 
  {

    if ( sizeof( $where_fields ) != sizeof( $where_values ) ) {
      die( "Query error: where <strong>field</strong> count doesn't match <strong>value</strong> count!" );
    } 
    else {

      $where = ' WHERE ';
      $p = 0;
      foreach ( $where_fields as $key => $value ) {
        $where .= $key . ' ' . $value . '= :p' . $p . ' ';
        $p++;
      }
      $where = substr( $where, 0, -1 );

      echo $query = "SELECT " . $fields . " FROM " . $tables . $where . $order . $limit; // . '<br>';
      $qp = $pdo_db->prepare( $query );

      foreach ( $where_values as $key => $val ) {
        $qp -> bindParam( ":p$key", $val, PDO::PARAM_INT );
        //echo ":p$key" . '<br>';
      }

    }

  } 
  else {
    echo $query = "SELECT " . $fields . " FROM " . $tables . $order . $limit;
    $qp = $pdo_db->prepare( $query );
  }
}
```

When remove the comments for output I get this as a result (seems ok to me)

```
SELECT * FROM list WHERE id= :p0 OR id= :p1 ORDER BY id DESC
:p0
:p1
```

Comment: That works as intended. I am talking about the situation when all IFs pass but a query `SELECT * FROM list WHERE id=? OR id=? ORDER BY id DESC` with params `1 2 and 2 8` return only the result with the `ID=8`.

Comment: @DainisAbols Sorry, I must have misread your question. Could you try my adjusted answer?

Comment: Still the same result with only the last param.

Comment: Something is not quite right: `SELECT * FROM list WHERE id= :p 1OR id= :p ORDER BY id DESC` and the error `Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`

Array
(
)
`

Comment: Ahhh .. a space at the wrong place in part 3 and a missing `;` Updated

Comment: Still the same: `SELECT * FROM bank_list WHERE id= :p1 OR id= :p2 ORDER BY id DESC` and the error `Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`

Comment: I typed in the whole stuff, could you try again?

Comment: No errors but the result is exactly the same what I started with: `SELECT * FROM list WHERE  id=8 OR id='8' ORDER BY id DESC` I get twice the same ID.

Comment: Did you mean `SELECT * FROM list WHERE id=2 OR id=8 ORDER BY id DESC` (no quote and id's 2 and 8)

Comment: Yes. I thought that was obvious ;) This is just a test query, so and `IN` comment wont help here.